# Angular FormControl Datatype (number)?

Tags: angular

Using Angular FormControl for `text` and `number` inputs. My problem is that both are recorded as text.

```
var control = this._formBuilder.control(this.settings[input.property]);
control.valueChanges.subscribe((value: any) => {
  console.log(typeof value);
  console.log(value);
});
```

And my inputs look like this-

```
<input [name]="input.property"
    [formControl]="control"
    [type]="inputElementType"
    class="form-control" id="form_control_1" placeholder="">
```

If I set `type="number"` it works fine. But being dynamic like this sets the right type on the dom, but doesn't register properly with the `formControl`.

I've tried-

```
[type]="inputElementType"
[type]="getInputElementType()"
type="{{getInputElementType()}}"
```

And none of these set the `formControl` properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is impossible since type is not an @input but part of selector. You can implement your own ControlValueAccessor that takes type as input. Here is NumberValueAccessor from Angular:

```
@Directive({
 selector:
    'input[type=number][formControlName],input[type=number]
   [formControl],input[type=number][ngModel]',
 ...
})
```

Comment: Interesting. I feel like that can cause problems later. For now I've just created an ngSwitch for my types and wrap the entire input with the static type there.